# How to use the sort function in excel without messing with the texts I've used concatenate for in other cells

Tags: excel, sorting, concatenation

I've developed a program for Qaballah that has text in one column and numeric values in another. In order to combine a series of verses in a text, I use concatenate formula in excel, but when I want to use the sort function ( ie smallest sum to largest sum) I lose all the concatenation I've been using. Do you know of any way around this or perhaps some type of macros.

Comment: You are simply sorting on the wrong collection of columns. Show sample data together with expected results or wait until I locate (one of the many) duplicate of this question on sorting with formulas.

Comment: I've tries to copy the data from excel, but it looks too convoluted, so i'll attempt to explain. In column A I have Arabic text Sometimes several lines long using concatenate to put together a series of verses (ie 1-8, 2-8,3 -8 etc.) In column B I have the numeric value for each series of verses, or in some cases single words or phrases. I want to place the numeric values in ascending order from lowest to highest, but when I use the sort function the concatenated words become jumbled (and yes I know to expand the sort!).

Comment: I'm also including a copy of my python program to see if there is a way to sort the data in the sum dictionary in ascending order and still display the other dictionaries in the "bigdict"  

def main():

Comment: wb = load_workbook(filename ="F:\\Quran Gematria.xlsm", data_only=True)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']

    bigdict = {}

    rowcount = 0

    for row in ws.rows:

        rowdict = {}

        rowdict['words'] = row[0].value
        rowdict['sum'] = row[1].value
        rowdict['prime']=row[2].value
        rowdict['deg/min/sec'] = row[4].value
        rowdict['translation'] = row[5].value